# Inject spring component in seam test class

Tags: java, spring, seam, testng

I use Seam 2.2, Spring 3.1, TestNG and DBUnit. I'm trying to instantiate a seam component in a simple TEST class:

```java
@Test
public void testGetCalendarInfo() throws Exception {

    new ComponentTest() {

        @Override
        protected void testComponents() throws Exception {
            String startDateParam = "21/07/1989 00:00:00";
            String endDateParam = "22/07/1989 00:00:00";

            CalendarAction calendarAction = (CalendarAction) 
                    Component.getInstance(CalendarAction.class, true);
            String jsonString = calendarAction.getCurrentEvents(startDateParam, endDateParam);
            Assert.assertEquals(jsonString, INFORMATION_LIST_JSON);
        }

    }.run();
```

All my seam components are using/injecting spring JDBC template. So when i'm trying to instantiate CalendarAction I'm getting :

```
org.jboss.seam.RequiredException: @In attribute requires non-null value: calendarAction.#{springNamedParameterJdbcTemplate}.
```

In src/test/resources I made a new WEB-INF folder where I put components.xml and beans.xml but it doesn't seem to work...

Comment: Why the downvote? Can anyone suggest improvements or corrections to this?

Comment: Can you provide the code of `CalenderAction` class?